# libertine font package doesn't work anymore (December 2011)

Tags: fonts, errors, pdftex, libertine

If you're using an up-to-date system and you're having trouble with using the Linux Libertine fonts, you should probably check out [Linux Libertine package and fonts not working anymore (fall 2012)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78516/4012), which deals with the current situation. The situation described in this question and its answer **do not apply anymore** to current systems.

---

Ever since an update in December 2011, `libertine` doesn't work anymore at all, the standard Computer Modern fonts are used instead. The minimal

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Hello World.
\end{document}
```

produces the error message

```
! Package libertine Error: Package is deprecated, use libertineotf!.
```

If I proceed accordingly and use `libertineotf` instead of `libertine`, I get 11 errors and no output:

```
! Package libertineotf Error: runs only with xelatex and lualatex!.
```

...

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
! 
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.
! 
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"
! instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H .
!...............................................
```

I am indeed compiling with pdfLaTeX, but I don't want to switch to Xe/LuaLaTeX. Is there any way to get back the Linux Libertine fonts with pdfLaTeX?

<sub>I know the answer to this question, but I thought this matter is worth sharing -- expecting some Googlers looking for help. I've seen the answer in a couple of comments on here, so I'll [wait a bit](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/asking-a-question-and-answering-it-yourself-straight-away), assuming the answer will pop up.</sub>

Comment: In their infinite wisdom, the developers of Linux Libertine decided to drop support for `pdflatex`. As Herbert points out, the old package has been restored.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Update your system, then you'll get the old `libertine` package as `libertine-legacy` and then it should work as usual. The new package `libertineotf` supports only `xetex` and `luatex`.

With the current TeXLive and MiKTeX as of end of 2012 there is only *one* package `libertine.sty` which can be used as

```
\usepackage[options]{libertine}
```

Depending on what was run (xelatex/lualatex/pdflatex), it loads by itself the package `fontspec` or `fontenc` and does all the configuration.

Comment: Additional: You will perhaps have to delete/rename the libertine.sty in libertineotf and update your file name data base so that your system finds and uses the libertine.sty from libertine-legacy.

Comment: Works, thank you. Just to clarify: "as usual" means you still load `\usepackage{libertine}`, _not_ `\usepackage{libertine-legacy}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: In my MiKTeX 2.9, the folder containing the `libertine.sty` that had to be deleted (or just renamed, as I did) is called `libertine`, and not `libertineotf`. It seems like this deletion has to be done again every time `libertine(otf)` is updated, right?

Comment: @doncherry: Yes the folder of the `libertineotf`-package is called `libertine`. And yes you would have to delete the sty after every update. A way to get around this could be to copy the `libertine.sty` from `libertine-legacy` to a local tree which is searched earlier. (And you would have to do it every time the sty in `libertine-legacy` is updated, but this shouldn't happen very often).

Comment: Some comments, because things have changed. The `libertine-legacy` package doesn't exist any more; one can load `libertine-type1` and `biolinum-type1`. As of today,  a package `libertine` exists that should work similarly to the old package with the same name.

Comment: @egreg the new `type1` packages appear to have changed a few things, e.g the `\libertineGlyph` command is missing. I created a follow-up question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76305/how-does-libertine-type1-work