# Problem with libertine font for pretty big quotes

Tags: fonts, punctuation, libertine

The following code, that I used with success, does not work with the last TeX LIve distribution. I don't know why.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
    {\fontsize{32}{32}\selectfont''}
    {\fontfamily{fxl}\fontsize{32{32}\selectfont''}
\end{document}
```

Here is what is produced.

[image]

How can I continue to have pretty quotes ?

Comment: "does not work" how? Does the document compile but there are errors? Fails to compile? What error messages do you get in the log file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The libertine-legacy font has been replaced, try:

```
\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineO-LF}\fontsize{32}{32}\selectfont
```

#### Portability

If you want to make your code as portable as possible (Libertine has only been replaced recently, and has not been replaced for MiKTeX users) use:

```
\IfFileExists{libertine-type1.sty}{
    \fontfamily{LinuxLibertineO-LF}\fontsize{32}{32}\selectfont 
}{
    \fontfamily{fxl}\fontsize{32}{32}\selectfont
}
```

This checks if the new libertine package is installed and defines your command based on that.

For old style figures, use `LinuxLibertineO-OsF` instead of `LinuxLibertineO-LF`.

#### Issues

If you don't use the `libertine` package, bold might not work.
To fix this, you either have to redefine `\bfdefault`:

```
\renewcommand*{\bfdefault}{b}
```

Or you'll have to change the way you use your quotes: don't use `\bfseries` or `\textbf` and define your font like this:

```
\fontfamily{fxl}\fontsize{32}{32}\fontseries{b}\selectfont
```

Letters available are `m` (medium) `b` (bold) and `sb` (semibold).

#### Example

```
\noindent
{\fontfamily{fxl}\fontsize{32}{32}\fontseries{m}\selectfont `'}
{\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineO-LF}\fontsize{32}{32}\fontseries{m}\selectfont `'}
{\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineO-LF}\fontsize{32}{32}\fontseries{sb}\selectfont `'}
{\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineO-LF}\fontsize{32}{32}\fontseries{b}\selectfont `'}
```

[image: fancy quotes]

Comment: Thanks for the information about libertine, and also for your solutions.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! It seems you know your way around with the latest round of `libertine`-replacement-packages. I haven't quite figured them out like that. Do you think you could ask a pseudo-question like http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39924 regarding these changes, potentially answering it yourself if nobody else does? Just pretend you're a innocent user, who dutifully updated their distribution and is surprised to learn that `libertine` once again has changed its behavior. Let me know if you have any questions, we could talk e.g. in [chat].

Comment: I'm glad you like it. I'll see if I can create a nice pseudo-question!