# How does "libertine-type1" work?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, libertine, type1

I am really struggling to understand how the packages `libertine-type1` and `biolinum-type1` work now that `libertine-legacy` is depreciated. According to the new `libertine.sty` all options when using `\usepackage{libertine}` are directly passed to the new type1 packages.

But that's not accurate and I can't get it to work because options such as `\libertineGlyph` do not exist anymore in any `sty` file.

I would be grateful if someone could shed some light on this issue and explain to me how you get the new packages work in the same way as the old one does.

This question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39924/libertine-font-package-doesnt-work-anymore) is related.

Comment: package options are passed, to the (new libertine and biolinum) packages; this has nothing to do with the function (not option) `\libertineGlyph` which appeared in the libertine-legacy package.  as was mentioned in the earlier question you link, libertine-legacy wasn't working and it turned out that the author was no longer interested.  hence the _simple_ libertine/biolinum-type1 fonts that only have a limited range of glyphs; the old author didn't help, so the new -type1 fonts just have standard type 1 glyphs in 'em.

Comment: @wasteofspace So in fact `libertine-type1` is libertine with much less functionality? And how was `libertine-legacy` not working? I've been using it since it was released without any trouble.

Comment: @Jörg I've got thousands of documents with Libertine and I use things like \libertineGlyph. So I downloaded the libertine-legacy package, installed it in my TEXMFHOME tree (which was not that easy) and now let's forget about this mess. Advantage of open source software: we can do that.

Comment: @KeksDose as you said it was not really easy to install the font. As I am creating templates that used libertine-legacy for other people this will be a big mess when they update their distributions.

Comment: @Jörg So you need a precise Howto for your folks. Either you ask here about the Howto or on a German speaking list (I assume that your native language is German).

Comment: @KeksDose I know how to install fonts, but it's not feasible for users that need/want/require an out-of-the-box solution. As far as I know there are only two packages for Type 1 fonts that have "professionell" features (alternative glyphs, osf, lining, proportional, monospaced): MinionPro, which always required manual installation and Linux Libertine. The latter was brilliantly easy to use, but now causes unnecessary pain... But I should stop whining now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason the people behind the old `libertine` package decided a while back they didn't want to maintain the `type1` versions any more. Libertine was split between `libertineotf` and `libertine-legacy`, the latter now has lost support altogether and has been replaced by `libertine-type1` and `biolinum-type1`.

The good news is all the functionality from the old `libertine` package is still available in `libertineotf`. The bad news is you can't use it with `pdflatex`.

## The new libertine package

The new `libertine` package now loads `libertine-type1` and `biolinum-type1` and passes all options to these packages. These packages to not provide any commands like `\libertineGlyph`. According to [the documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/libertine-type1) the following options are available:

```
oldstyle,osf    old-style figures
lining,nf       lining figures

proportional    varying-width figures
tabular         fixed-width figures

bold            \bfdefault is bold
semibold        \bfdefault is semibold
```

However, `osf` and `nf` do not work.

## The libertineotf package.

If you are a XeLaTeX or a LuaLaTeX user, the `libertineotf` package provides the functionality available in the old package. Unfortunately it [has some issues of its own](https://github.com/pgundlach/linuxlibertine/issues/3).

## Further reading

- [libertine font package doesn't work anymore (December 2011)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39924/libertine-font-package-doesnt-work-anymore-december-2011)
- [Linux Libertine package and fonts not working anymore (fall 2012)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78516/linux-libertine-package-and-fonts-not-working-anymore-fall-2012)
- [Libertine-type1 on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/libertine-type1)
- [Libertineotf on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/libertineotf/) or [Github](https://github.com/pgundlach/linuxlibertine).

Comment: What I don't understand is why they remove a good working package (libertine-legacy) even if it would not have been developed anymore, and replace it with a stripped down and almost useless version. It's not as if libertine-legacy was somehow broken...

Comment: @Jörg: It might seem strange to replace the package, but it does make sense to replace a package that is no longer being maintained by one that is. Also: you can still download `libertine-legacy` [from CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertine-legacy). Some more instructions can be found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78520/17484).

Comment: we removed -legacy from the main ctan tree because (we were told) there were serious problems with it, which the author said he wasn't interested in. (iirc, we were told there would be no support, when the package was first installed, but i at least had forgotten.)

Comment: @Silex Aren't there dozens of packages on CTAN (and in MikTeX/TeXLive) distributions that are no longer maintained?

Comment: @wasteofspace I have installed `libertine-legacy` but as I am occasionally creating templates for other people, and this was the only free Type1 font I know of that had proportional/monospaced lining/old style figures I used it heavily. Hence it is really frustrating that it has been removed.

Comment: @Jörg: True! The current situation with Linux Libertine basically is like "DLL hell" on Windows was in the 90s. What a shame!

Comment: @Jörg: I'm sure that most unmaintained packages will be replaced when there is a maintained alternative. Also: the new `libertine-type1` package does have proportional/monospaced lining/old style figures.  
Until someone ports all other features I'm afraid you are stuck with `libertine-type1` and `libertineotf`.

Answer (score 2):

The `\libertineGlyph` macro is in general nothing else than using `\char` with the additional setting of font encoding and shape. If you absoluetely need it, you can copy the command definition from `libertine-legacy`. Needs only the command `\DeclareTextGlyphX` and the additional definition files for the glyphs. However, you do not really need that command.

The "new" package `libertine` simplifies the loading of `libertine-type1` and `biolinum-type1` and provides compatibility for all those documents which used
`\usepackage{libertine}`.

Comment: I don't really see how a package can provide "compatibility for all those documents which used \usepackage{libertine}" when there are functions from the original package missing...anyway I will try and restore functionality as good as I can...

Comment: I do not know a lot of users who use the additional macros of libertine. And yes, that commands are all not defined. But that was _not_ intended by the new package