# Why is libertineotf font under "obsolete" directory?

Tags: xetex, libertine, ctan

Looking up [libertineotf](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertineotf) package on CTAN:, its sources live under the `obsolete` directory: http://mirror.ctan.org/obsolete/fonts/libertineotf.

Does this mean this package is obsolete? Is there an updated package for Libertine for XeLaTeX?

Answer (score 5):

The first libertine fonts (always including the sans serif Biolinum) were the Type 1 ones and supported by the first package `libertine`. After some time the fonts where provided as OpenType and supported by the package `libertineotf`. For some reason the package was renamed to `libertine` and the old one was renamed to `libertine-legacy` (supports only Type 1). Both packages moved to `obsolete` because the current package `libertine` supports both types of the fonts: OpenType and Type1. But it is still different in its behaviour to the old package for the Type 1 version, e.g. SmallCaps

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the package to use is the `libertine` package. From the documentation:

> This package provides support for use of the Linux Libertine and Linux Biolinum families of fonts in LaTeX. Most features are usable with LaTeX and dvips, pdfLaTeX, xeLaTeX and luaLaTeX; the features in Section 5 are only usable with xeLaTeX or luaLaTeX. This package compatibly replaces several earlier packages (`libertine-type1`, `biolinum-type1`, `libertine`) and should provide partial compatibility with the obsolete `libertineotf` and `libertine-legacy` packages.

Despite the somewhat ominous sounding language that the new package provides "partial compatibility" with the old packages, I don't think you should be concerned about the old packages too much.

For some more context on the history of the packages see:

- [How does "libertine-type1" work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76305/2693)